# What methods or procedures need to be in place to append in jQuery a simple Java 'class' instance that represents a jQuery implementation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

I have this class in Javascript: call it **Caption**:

```
function Caption
{
   var ...

   function get...()
   { }

   function set...(...)
   { ... }

   return( {   get...:   get...
           ,   set...:   set...
           });
}
```

This is only one component of a larger system and is part of an outer class called **Filter**.  I would love to be able to when creating the jQuery for the object to be able to say:

```
tblFilter.append(getCaption())
```

which would get the Caption class instance variable and append the jQuery representation of it.  Do I need to inherit from jQuery to make that happen?  Like this?

```
function Caption
{
   var ...

   function get...()
   { }

   function set...(...)
   { ... }

   var that = jQuery();

   that.get... = get...;
   that.set... = set...;

   return(that);
}
```

?

If that's true, what I'm not sure of is what function/method I need to write to produce the jQuery that is produced to be appended to the outer jQuery.  Does this make sense and if so, what am I missing?

Edit:

Let me elaborate - Ok I'm creating my own version of a Data Table.  Yes I know jQueryUI has but with this, I pass the data and it renders the data.  There's a Filter component that really can't be created/constructed publicly but just accessed by a getFilter() method.  Every time the Filter instance is changed, thanks to a home grown listener/observer/observable pattern, the filter is erased and re-rendered.  As of now much of it is hard coded.  When I first wrote it it was more loosely written as it was for a programming assignment to get a job and I did it within 2 days I had.  Now that it's done I'm trying to implement it more generically into a library.  When I get to appending the Caption and trying to make it render it based on the Caption object, I have no ID for a Caption or a parent object to remove.  Ideally I'd love to be able to do:

```
var objDataTable = new DataTable(/*parameters*/);
$(/*parent selector/*).append(objDataTable);
```

Comment: What about `$(getCaptionElement())`?

Comment: The problem with $(getCaptionElement()) is that the method doesn't exist yet but if I were to add it, are you suggesting writing one that just returned the string that would go into HTML?  What I'm producing right now in many of the objects is as such:  

return(
   $("<div></div>,  {id: "blah", css: {margin:  "0 auto"}})
      .append(/*Other stuff*/)
      .append(...));

The idea is to have jQuery write the HTML for me but Thank you

Comment: I think your question should be ... how to extend JQuery ?

Comment: I know how to extend jQuery - I can add functions to jQuery until my face is blue.  What I don't know is how to make my class appear like a jQuery object and for JQuery to append what I want - that 2nd part is the important part."for jQuery to append what I want"

Answer (score 0):

I'm self taught so my Object Oriented Programming is a bit all over the place, but if I had a class, that I wanted to 'HTMLize' and insert values from into the dom, I would do it like this:

```
var Caption = {

  'amount':10,
  'word':'Hello!',
  'getCaption': function(appendToObject){
    var div = $('<div />');
    var ul = $('<ul />');
    var li = $('<li />', {
      'text' : this.word
    });
    li.appendTo(ul);
    var li2 = $('<li />', {
      'text' : this.amount
    });
    li2.appendTo(ul);
    ul.appendTo(div);
    div.appendTo(appendToObject);
  }

};

var caption_instance = Caption;

caption_instance.getCaption('#wrapper');


var second_caption = Caption;
second_caption.amount = 13;
second_caption.word = 'Goodbye';
caption_instance.getCaption('#wrapper');
```

You can see it in action here:

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/bVrapW

If you are including jQuery globally you don't need to pass anything to the function, you can just get going.

The important part here is the `var xxx = $('<DOM_TAG />');` which lets you create elements to append to the DOM. This can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2

If I've misunderstood the question just let me know and I'll remove the answer.

Comment: I will give this consideration - I have off today and this is a personal project  but hopefully will be able to play w/ this and get back to you by end of the day tomorrow.  Thanks Djave!

Comment: `var caption_instance = Caption;` and `var second_caption = Caption;` point to the same reference, was that intended ?